# Overridden setSelected and setHighlighted doesn't retain selected background when scrolls out of view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

My `setSelected` for my reuse `UITableViewCell` looks like so (as does my `setHighlighted`):

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  if selected {
    backgroundColor = .red
  } else {
    backgroundColor = .white
  }
}
```

Whenever the cell scrolls out and then back into view the background color is changed back to the default white. It is as if the cell is not retaining its selected state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `setSelected` would get called which would change it to the correct background color if the cell was selected, then `setHighlighted` would get called and as my cell was not highlighted it would change my cell back to the default white.

I have simply taken out the content from within my `setHighlighted` implementation and it has solved my issue.